# Using Styled-Map with PolishedJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have the following [Styled-Map](https://github.com/scf4/styled-map) object:

```
export const colorProps = styledMap({
  default: yellow,
  primary: blue,
  secondary: green,
})
```

I use it as follows in a Styled Component:

```
const MyComponent = styled.div`
  ...

  background-color: ${colorProps};
  ...
`
```

This then allows me to use my component as follows:

```
<MyComponent primary />
<MyComponent secondary />
```

And it will use the appropriate color value for the background-color.

So far, so good.

But now I would like to use [polished](https://polished.js.org/) to darken the background-color on hover -- something like this:

```
&:hover {
  background-color: ${darken(0.1, colorProps)};
}
```

But this does not work.  It throws an error.

```
Error: Passed an incorrect argument to a color function, please pass a string representation of a color.
```

I am wondering, therefore, if anyone has any ideas on how I can use styled-map in conjunction with polished?

Answer (score 0):

> [**darken**](https://polished.js.org/docs/#darken)
>   Returns a string value for the darkened color.
>
> `darken(amount: (number | string), color: string): string`

As 2nd argument, you need to pass a `string` where `colorProps` in your case is a `function`.

Therefore, pass the `props` object from `styled-components` to `colorProps`:

```
const COLORS = {
  default: 'yellow',
  primary: 'blue',
  secondary: 'green'
};

const colorProps = styledMap(COLORS);

const FlexBox = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => darken(0.1, colorProps(props))};

  // border: 30px solid ${props => colorProps(props)};
  border: 30px solid ${colorProps};
  height: 100px;
`;

const App = () => {
  return <FlexBox secondary />;
};
```

[image: Edit Q-58341645-styledMap-polished]